# Symfony, Swift Mailer, CRON JOBS, & Shared Hosting Server

Tags: symfony, cron, symfony-1.4, shared-hosting, swiftmailer

Before I tackle this solution, I wanted to run it by the community to get feedback.

Questions:

1. Is my approach feasible?  i.e. can it even be done this way?
2. Is it the right/most efficient solution?
3. If it isn’t the right solution, what would be a better approach?

Problems:

1. Need to send mass emails through the application.
2. The shared hosted server only permits a maximum of 500 emails to be sent per hour before getting labeled a spammer
3. Server timeout while sending batch emails

Proposed Solution:

Upon task submittal (i.e. the user provides all necessary email information using a form and frontend template, selects the target audience, etc..), the action will then:

1. Determines how many records (from a stored db of contacts) the email will be sent to
2. If the number of records in #1 above is more than 400:
3. Assign a batch number to all these records in the DB.
4. Run a CRON job that:
5. Every hour, selects 400 records in batch “X” and sends the saved email template until there are no more records with batch “X”.  Each time a batch of 400 is sent, it’s batch number is erased (so it won’t be selected again the following hour).
6. If there is an unfinished CRON JOB scheduled ahead of it (i.e. currently running), it will be placed in a queue.

Other clarification: 
To send these emails I simply iterate over the SWIFT mailer using the following code:

```
 foreach($list as $record)
 {
      mailers::sendMemberSpam($record, $emailParamsArray); 
      // where the above simply contains: sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer()->send($message); 
 }
```

*where $list is the list of records with a batch_number of “X”.

I’m not sure this is the most efficient of solutions, because it seems to be bogging down the server, and will eventually time out if the list or email is long.

So, I’m just looking for opinions at this point... thanks in advance.

Comment: Re: Mailing -- I would contact your host.. any shared hosting I have used in the past completely outlaws sending emails in a throttled fashion. You can throttle emails on a VPS or Dedicated server, but not on a shared. For example, host gator allows 500 per hour, but you cannot throttle a larger list into multiple hours. The purpose is for transactional emails to be able to go each hour, not a giant mailing list.

Comment: The host I am referring to is Hostgator, and I did contact them.  They actually recommended PHPList, which is an available plugin which does allow throttling on a shared server.  However, I would have no idea where to begin getting my symfony app to talk to PHPList plugin.  Which is why I came up with the above solution.  And I'm trying to automate the entire process as well.

Comment: Also: batch sizes will not exceed 2,500

Comment: I have no hands-on experience with PHPList, but ideally you would create a Model, implement the PHP list plugin and set the new Model to be a service that gets your service.container as an argument. Then just pull in your model from your controller and do the work.

Comment: I would love to know what happened here... Trying to send emails using symfony and swiftmailer in a cronjob task (transactional) but from the clients shared hosting emails are not being sent. It's hard to debug as there is nog debug bar and not much to go on in the logs :(